# NestJs - DTO with chield entities

Tags: node.js, nestjs, entity, dto

I'm working with some entities there is for people, so some people may have relationship with another one.

For exemple, family relations, my entity would be:

```
@Entity()
export class Person {
  @Column({ length: 100 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ length: 20 })
  document: string;

... 
and many other properties
...

  @ManyToOne(() => Person, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'father_id',
    foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_person_father',
  })
  father: Person;

  @ManyToOne(() => Person, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'mother_id',
    foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_person_mother',
  })
  father: Person;
```

For the DTO, I was just using like that

```
export class CreatePersonDto {
  name: string;
  document: string;
...
  father: Person;
  mother: Person;
}
```

The problem is that in every place that I'm using this DTO I need to give all of the father and mother properties, like name and document, but i only need its id, there is there relation.

There's some approaches:

1. All of person properties can be nullable. (name?: string, document? string ...)
2. Create a "getPersonDTO" with all of the properties nullable, except the id.
3. Change then mother and father properties to number.

I don't know how is the best practice with that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this issue is to create a **separate DTO** for the **father** and **mother** properties that only includes the `id` field.

this way, you can use this **DTO** in places where you only need the **id** of the **father** or **mother**, and use the full `CreatePersonDto` where you need all the properties.

how you can create a separate **DTO** for the **father** and **mother** properties:

```
export class PersonRelationDto {
  id: number;
}

export class CreatePersonDto {
  name: string;
  document: string;
  // ...
  father: PersonRelationDto;
  mother: PersonRelationDto;
}
```

on this example, the `PersonRelationDto` class only includes the `id` field, which is the only field you need to represent the **relationship between two persons**. `CreatePersonDto` class still includes the full **father** and **mother** properties, but you can use the `PersonRelationDto` class in places where you only need the `id`.

if you want to create a **new person** with a **father** and **mother**, you can use the full `CreatePersonDto`:

```
const createPersonDto: CreatePersonDto = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  document: '123456789',
  father: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe Sr.',
    document: '987654321',
    // ...
  },
  mother: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    document: '567890123',
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};
```

If you only need the `id` of the **father** or **mother**, you can use the `PersonRelationDto`:

```
const fatherDto: PersonRelationDto = {
  id: 1,
};

const motherDto: PersonRelationDto = {
  id: 2,
};
```

This approach allows you to use the full `CreatePersonDto` where you need all the properties, and the `PersonRelationDto` where you only need the `id`.

Thank you.